# Create record from resque worker failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, resque

I am using Resque in rails. I have a model called Post for which I want to create new records from rescue worker class. I am unable to create the record. If I try the same thing in a controller, it works fine. Please advise what could be going wrong

Resque Class

```
class ImageProcessor
    @queue = :image_queue

    def self.perform(tags)

        count = 1
        tags.map do |p|

          post = Post.new(username: "hello", address:"123")
          post.save!
       end
end
```

This is unable to create a new Post record. (This is in file app/workers/image_processor.rb)

While if I call it from controller, it works fine

In home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

    def index

    end

    def method1
        post = Post.new(username: "hello", address:"123")
        post.save!
    end
end
```

Whats going wrong? Why can't I do the same thing in resque worker class, which I can to in a controller

Comment: What does the log say? Also, how do you run the worker? Is sidekiq process running?

Comment: I dont see any log. Where do I see the log? It is not a sidekiq process. I run the resque worker using the following command on shell "bundle exec rake environment resque:work QUEUE=image_queue"

Comment: This command only starts the sidekiq process. Sidekiq is then waiting for you to add any job to the queue, which you need to do in your code with `ImageProcessor.perform_async(tags)`

Comment: I am not using sidekiq, but resque. I call resque.enqueue(ImageProcessor, tags) from HomeController class. The other tasks defined in self.perform(tags) method are executed, but the new record is not created. Also I dont see any error being thrown

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see perform and I think sidekiq. Anyway try adding `Resque.logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join 'log', 'resque.log') before you queue the job and check what has been logged.

Comment: OK. Will try the logger. The problem was solved though once I restarted the resque and rails server. Its working fine now. Thanks